# Java servlet skips one db reading after server resart

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

so I just started learning java EE, and I made a simple servlet that counts visitors with database. The best choice would be to add entry every time visitor opens site and to simply read last entry's auto increment field(primary key), this way I can also save dates and times of visits and such. 
But since I am learning I chose to do silly stuff to experiment and I have this database:

id = 1 , visits = 21 .

For each visitor servlet updates the visits variable to new number. It works as long as i don't restart server. When I do servlet skips reading and just starts counting form what ever value variable visits is set to (database itself does not reset).
problem is I have old laptop so I don't wanna make a local server for testing, would take hours, instead I use openshift tomcat7 and I don't know how to check logs of errors there.

its just a simple httpServlet and this is logic in my get method:

```
String sqlRead = "SELECT *my_cell* FROM *my_table* WHERE id = 1";
String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE *my_table* SET *my_cell*=? WHERE id = 1";
int visits = 0;


try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ResultSet qResult = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:mysql://IPI.P.IPI.P:PORT/dbname", "user", "pass")
            .createStatement().executeQuery(sqlRead);

        //i know this reader starts at index-1
        qResult.next();
        this.visits = qResult.getInt("visits");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e);
}

visits++;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection writeConnection = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:mysql://IPI.P.IPI.P:PORT/dbname", "user", "pass");

        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = writeConnection.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
        preparedStmt.setInt(1, this.visits);
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

    writeConnection.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex);
}
String visitsString = ""+visits;
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(visitsString);
```

Comment: 1) [Openshift logs](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202328880); 2) do not open more DB connections, use just one - opening a connection costs a lot of resources; 3) your code is a disaster from concurrency point of view: read and update should be processed in a transaction or in a `synchronized` block;

Comment: Whnever tomcat start, do you want to start counting from beginning?

Comment: ty Jozef, I am jumping on all those things! Gopal, I do not want to start counting from 0, it is a problem i want to correct :P

Comment: I'll put the read counter part in a static block... then just Jozef said... watch out for concurrency problem

Comment: why are there astericks around your table names?

Comment: btw, you should not be reading, incrementing in java, then updating. You should just do `"UPDATE *my_table* SET *my_cell*=*my_cell*+1 WHERE id = 1";` and I really don't think the `*`s should be there either.

Comment: i got carried away with hiding data so i renamed visits to *my_cell* for some reason... sorry about that.   developerwjk, the reason its so messy is because it was worked on and had things done to it (this is for purpose of understanding how things work  ) but you gave me a great idea to eliminate that local variable and see what happens when i do it like that. p.s. sync blocks didn't work yet, still reading up on that entire concurrency concept, didn't have much time this afternoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I got a working version, and I broke it off so database handling can go in new class. I didn't finish reading on concurrency but from I got so far is that servlets get handled by tomcat so I just synchronized functions, hope I did it right. Please correct any further mistakes. This is new version:

```
private int localVisits = -1;

String sqlRead = "SELECT visits FROM visitsTable WHERE id = 1;";
String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE visitsTable SET visits=visits+1 WHERE id = 1;";
Connection con;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PPPP/dbName", "user", "pass");
    } catch (Exception e) {}

//calling write new visitor to db function
    writeDBCounter();

//reading from db to send to frontend
    String report = "-2";
    try {
        report = "" + readDBCounter();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(report);
//closing connection
try {
    con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

// read
private synchronized int readDBCounter() throws SQLException {
    int newVisits = -1;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        java.sql.Statement s =con.createStatement();
        s.executeQuery(sqlRead);
         rs = s.getResultSet();
        rs.next();
        newVisits = rs.getInt("visits");


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.print(ex);
    }
    rs.close();
    return newVisits;
}

// write
private synchronized void writeDBCounter() {
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```